# Can I use the IBM Social Business Toolkit to consume Office365 services?

Tags: java, oauth, ibm-sbt

I have played with the Google OAuth java libraries, but I in fact I want to consume Office365 content in a Connections environment.

My question is, how can I implement the code described in the question below with the new IBM SBT SDK ?

[How to map variable from SPAppToken into AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544723/how-to-map-variable-from-spapptoken-into-authorizationcodetokenrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason you couldn't use the sbt/Endpoint and the configurations to consume any REST services, however I'm unsure if you would need to do anything beyond that (security wise) that might require more work.

Does it work with Basic?

Comment: No I tried BasicAuthentication, but I could only get it to work with ClientCredentials.